# Ansi C - function expecting pointer to array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, ansi-c

im writting program in ANSI C, and and have one function, where im passing pointer to  semaphores array `struct sembuf semb[5]`.

Now header of that function looks like:

```
void setOperations(struct sembuf * op[5], int nr, int oper)
```

But im getting warning:

```
safe.c:20: note: expected ‘struct sembuf **’ but argument is of type ‘struct sembuf (*)[5]’
```

How to solve that problem?

**Edit**
Calling:

```
setOperations(&semb, prawa, -1);
```

Comment: What does your function call look like?

Comment: you're expected to derefetence the pointer twice and you're not. show the code of the actual call

Comment: Ah, i forgot: setOperations(&semb, prawa, -1);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the function should be declared if you want to pass a pointer to an array and not an array of pointers:

```
void setOperations(struct sembuf (*op)[5], int nr, int oper);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current declaration (`struct sembuf * op[5]`) means an array of 5 pointers to `struct sembuf`.

Arrays are passed as pointer anyway, so in the header you need: `struct sembuf op[5]`.
A pointer to the array will be passed anyway. No array will be copied.
Alternative way of declaring this argument would be `struct sembuf *op`, which is a pointer to `struct sembuf`.

Comment: Uhm. So, how to declare header for pointer to array of 5 structs?

Comment: A pointer to array of 5 structs is the same as a pointer to this array's first element in C terminology. There is no additional information hidden in a C array, than the address to the first element, so there is no need for explicit pointer.

Comment: This is not what im asking actually :P I understood, i can pass a pointer to first element and will be good. I also know now how to pass pointer to array (Vaughn Cato response). Thx anyway

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you shouldn't change where that array starts if it was first declared on stack, as you may get serious memory leaks  if you do.

Comment: I wont change it, i just want to know address. I think i need to, because I'm reading that array from multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe over complicating this...

If you want to pass an array of structures, it's really no different than passing any array of anythings. Once you have the array, getting the address is simple, let me give you a quick example:

Let's say you have this struct:

```
typedef struct s {
    int a;
    int b;
} mys;
```

If you want to declare it statically in your `main()` you can do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mys local[3];
    memset(local, 0, sizeof(mys)*3);   // Now we have an array of structs, values are 
                                       // initialized to zero.

    // as a sanity check let's print the address of our array:
    printf("my array is at address: %#x\n", local);

    changeit(local, 3);  // now we'll pass the array to our function to change it
```

Now we can have our function that accepts the array and changes the values:

```
void changeit(mys remote[], int size)
{
    int count;
    printf("my remote array is at address: %#x\n", remote); //sanity check
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        remote[count].a = count;
        remote[count].b = count + size;
    }
}
```

Once that returns we can print the values from `main()` with some other loop like:

```
for(int count = 0; count < 3; count ++)
    printf("struct[%d].a = %d\n struct[%d].b = %d\n", 
           count, local[count].a, count, local[count].b);
```

And we'll get some output that looks like:

```
>> ./a.out
   my array is at address: 0xbf913ac4
   my remote array is at address: 0xbf913ac4
   struct[0].a = 0
   struct[0].b = 3
   struct[1].a = 1
   struct[1].b = 4
   struct[2].a = 2
   struct[2].b = 5
```

So you can see it's the same array (same address) and that's how you get the array of structs to the other function. Did that clear it up?

Comment: I know Mike. Thanks. Vaughn Cato responsed for my question very well. I was passing array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. Thats all:) But thx ;)

Comment: @user1040813 - Cool, glad you got it!

Comment: @user1040813 - Am wondering however, why do you need to pass a pointer to an array?

Comment: @user1040813 - because arrays *decay into* pointers anyway. Thus it only obfuscates the code to pass a pointer to them. They're accessible "by reference" just passing the array, you don't need to deference them in the function you're working in, and you can get the address of the array without a pointer. So what does it really buy you to pass a pointer to an array?

Comment: I know that array is actually a pointer to a first element. I know. But it is just an example, for learning. When in future i will need pointer to array i will know how to do it (for example to malloc memory in other functions).